# Broadcast receiver for testing network state not working

Tags: android

I´m trying to check the internet connection of wifi and mobile through a BroadcastReceiver . A toast should show the connectivity changes .
I register the receiver but it doesn´t shows the changes .

```
    package com.axa.conetividad;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    //Muestra si el display debe de ser refrescada
    public static boolean availableConnection = false;
    public boolean isReceiverRegistered = false;

    NetworkReceiver networkReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        networkReceiver = new NetworkReceiver();
        registerReceiver();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(networkReceiver);
        isReceiverRegistered = false;
    }

    private void registerReceiver() {
        if (!isReceiverRegistered) {
            //Registra el BroadCastReceiver para hacer el track de la red
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(networkReceiver, filter);
            isReceiverRegistered = true;
        }
    }


    public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            //Monitoreamos la conexión
            ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                availableConnection = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, " wifi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                availableConnection = true;
                Toast.makeText(context, "mobile", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                availableConnection = false;
                Toast.makeText(context, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Here is my manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: You have register your reciever in Manifest file

Comment: The receiver is registered on execution time

Comment: Don't use `LocalBroadcastManager`, as the broadcast is not coming from your app, but from the system. Just use the `Activity`'s `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)` method.

Comment: jUST USE REGISTERRECIEVER()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `registerReceiver()` method of your activity ,

**So change this line**

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(networkReceiver, filter);
```

**to**

```
registerReceiver(networkReceiver,filter);
```

And dont forget to unregister your receiver in **onPause()** method

```
@Override
 protected void onPause() {
  if (networkReceiver != null) {
   unregisterReceiver(networkReceiver);
   networkReceiver = null
  }
  super.onPause();
 }
```

Comment: unregister should NOT happen in `onDestroy()` because there is no guarantee that runtime will call that. Receiver should be registered in `onResume()` and unregistered in `onPause()`

Comment: what???? onCreate() and onResume() will be called when app is started so there is no way this receiver cannot be registered in the first place. Secondly onDestroy() will be called when the app is exits so we  will be unregstering the receiver in onDestroy()

Comment: `onDestroy()` can be called when the application exists but it is not a 100%.  See the documentation. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29 I've had cases myself where receiver does not unregister or sharedpreference do not save on `onDestroy()`.  That is why `onPause()` should be used. and it is not called when the app is started but it is called when the Activity starts. there is a BIG BIG BIG difference

Comment: Thanks with the onDestroy() method i dint know about that. But i never encountered that while working

Comment: If I unregistered my receiver in onDestroy , it would cause an error because previously the receiver was unregistered in onResume.

Comment: Yea so unregister it in ondestroy